# How do I access an overridden data member in Scala?

Tags: scala, inheritance

How do I call an overridden data member in Scala? Here's an example from a worksheet -- I'd like to do something like:

```
trait HasWings {
  def fly() = println("I'm flying!")
  val wingType = "Thin"
}

class Bee extends HasWings {
  override def fly() = {
    println("Buzzzz! Also... ")
    super.fly()  // we can do this...
  }

  override val wingType = "Translucent and " + super.wingType  // ...but not this!
}

val bumble = new Bee()

bumble.fly()
println(s"${bumble.wingType}")
```

But I get the error, `super may not be used on value wingType`. **How can I override the data member while still getting access to it?** There are workarounds, like:

1. Not overriding the superclass value
2. Declaring the superclass value as a method

But I'm curious if I can have my override *and* my superclass data member access.

Thanks!

Comment: I just hit this and am scratching my head as to why? My use case is for a value that determines how long my object models get cached for. I simply want an exception that is 10 * whatever the system default happens to be. Yes I had an easy work around but shocked that I simply couldn't do `override val modelsCachedFor = 10 * super.modelsCachedFor`. I do NOT want to calculate that (trivial as it is) every time I cache an object instance -- I simply want to use the (new) value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the compiler tells you, scala does not allow to use `super` on a a `val`.
If you need this, you can refactor your code to use a `def` that is used to initialize the `val`. Then you can override the `def` instead:

```
trait HasWings {
  def wingType0: String = "Thin"
  val wingType = wingType0
}

class Bee extends HasWings {
  override def wingType0 = "Translucent and " + super.wingType0
}
```

Comment: So basically the answer is to use `def` instead of `val`, and use a workaround if I really want to use `val` in the superclass. This works in my worksheet. Thanks!

Comment: See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1938 for the long-standing but report.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible at all.